# Can't resolve issue with initializing a 2D array dynamically

Tags: c++, visual-studio, multidimensional-array

I am writing a program in which I have a grayscale image in a 3D array:

```
    FILE *file;
    const int BytesPerPixel = 1;
    const int Size = 512;
    fread(Imagedata, sizeof(unsigned char), Size*Size*BytesPerPixel, file);
    fclose(file);
```

I want to pad this image with zeros such that the image size inc by one pixel/row/col on every side. This is the code I wrote in my main():

```
    const int padSize = 1;
    const int newLength = Size + (2 * padSize), newBreadth = Size + (2 * padSize);

    unsigned char*** paddedImage = padImageWithZeros(Imagedata, newLength, newBreadth, BytesPerPixel, padSize);
```

The function def is in my Header file which has been included in the source.cpp:

```
    unsigned char*** initializeImage(const int length, const int breadth, const int channels)
    {

        unsigned char*** newImage = new unsigned char**[channels];
        for (int i = 0; i < channels ; ++i)
        {
            newImage[i] = new unsigned char*[length];

            for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j)
            {
                    newImage[i][j] = new unsigned char[breadth];

                for (int k = 0; k < breadth; ++k)
                {
                    newImage[j][k][i] = (unsigned char)0;
                }
            }
        }

        return newImage;
    }



    unsigned char*** padImageWithZeros(unsigned char Imagedata[512][512][1],const int newLength,const int newBreadth, const int BytesPerPixel, const int padSize)
    {
        //Initializing a 3 channel padded Image
        unsigned char*** paddedImage = initializeImage(newLength, newBreadth, BytesPerPixel);


       //Storing the original image in the padded image
       for (int channel = 0; channel < BytesPerPixel; channel++)
       {
            cout << "Channel = " << channel << endl;
            for (int i = padSize; i < newLength; i++)
            {
                for (int j = padSize; j < newBreadth ; j++)
                {
                    cout << paddedImage[i][j][channel] << endl;
                    cout << "Yes" << endl;
                    paddedImage[i][j][channel] = Imagedata[i - padSize][j - padSize][channel];
                }
            }
        }

    return paddedImage;
    }
```

However, after I checked the paddedImage matrix removed just after initializing and it looks something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MC6B.jpg)

and running the code in Visual Studio gives an Access Violation error at

```
    paddedImage[i][j][channel] = Imagedata[i - padSize][j - padSize][channel];
```

I have a feeling I am not initializing the paddedImage correctly, but I am not sure what's wrong. Please help.

EDIT: Updated code:
    The function call in main():

```
    const int padSize = 1;
    const int newLength = Size + (2 * padSize), newBreadth = Size + (2 * padSize);

    unsigned char*** paddedImage = padImageWithZeros(Imagedata, newLength, newBreadth, BytesPerPixel, padSize);
```

The function definitions in the Header. h:

```
    unsigned char*** initializeImage(const int length, const int breadth, const int channels)
    {
        unsigned char*** newImage = new unsigned char**[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
             newImage[i] = new unsigned char*[breadth];

             for (int j = 0; j < breadth; ++j)
             {
                  newImage[i][j] = new unsigned char[channels];

                  for (int k = 0; k < channels; ++k)
                  {
                      newImage[i][j][k] = (unsigned char)0;
                  }
              }
          }

           return newImage;
    }

    unsigned char*** padImageWithZeros(unsigned char Imagedata[512][512][1], const int newLength, const int newBreadth, const int BytesPerPixel, const int padSize)
    {
        //Initializing a 3 channel padded Image
        unsigned char*** paddedImage = initializeImage(newLength, newBreadth, BytesPerPixel);


       //Storing the original image in the padded image
       for (int channel = 0; channel < BytesPerPixel; channel++)
       {
           cout << "Channel = " << channel << endl;
           for (int i = padSize; i < newLength - padSize; i++)
       {
            for (int j = padSize; j < newBreadth - padSize; j++)
            {
                cout << paddedImage[i][j][channel] << endl;
                cout << "Yes" << endl;
                paddedImage[i][j][channel] = Imagedata[i - padSize][j - padSize][channel];
            }
        }
    }

    return paddedImage;
 }
```

OUTPUT:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRnQu.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptkoP.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 errors here:

- the `initializeImage` function, as already pointed out by @rafix07. You are initializing a `image[channel][lenght]breadth]` while you need a `image[lenght][breadth][channel]` (see his answer for the fixes needed in that function)
- the loop to copy the image, uses wrong ranges.

You should loop with something like:

```
//Storing the original image in the padded image
for (int channel = 0; channel < BytesPerPixel; channel++)
{
     cout << "Channel = " << channel << endl;
     for (int i = padSize; i < newLength - padSize; i++)
     {
         for (int j = padSize; j < newBreadth - padSize; j++)
         {
             cout << paddedImage[i][j][channel] << endl;
             cout << "Yes" << endl;
             paddedImage[i][j][channel] = Imagedata[i - padSize][j - padSize][channel];
         }
     }
 }
```

Please look at the for loop termination condition. In your solution, you are copying `newLength-padSize` elements from the original image, while you need to copy `newLength-(2*padSize)`.

I'd add that the way you are handling the image is not cache friendly. It should be at least `image[column][row][channels]`. Another huge improvement, can be provided by allocating a single dimension array of size `length * breadth * channels` and then use some member function to retrieve the pixel or color component you need like `getColor(x,y,channel)` or `setColor(newValue,x,y,channel)`. A single dimension array would provide you in the future an easy way for further optimizations (eg like using pointers)

Comment: I made both the edits, but I am still getting the same output

Comment: Could you post the updated code? As it must be reproducible, and it seems matter of details, please provide a complete example.

Comment: Besides some consideration on the coding style that you should improve, like: using a reference for the Imagedata parameter, it should be const (toensure you are reading from it), a `typedef unsigned char ImageBuffer[512][512][1]`. I suggest you to  change the second half of the "copy" instrcution from `Imagedata[i - padSize][j - padSize][channel];` to `Imagedata[i - padSize][j - padSize][1];`. That said, you are getting the same output: a crash or a wrong image?

Comment: Its not crashing, but I checked the pixel values of paddedImage right before I am assigning it the balues from Imagedata, as you can see in the code, and its blank. I think there is something wrong with the initialization.

Comment: Also,just verifying, shiuldn’t it be Imagedata[i - padSize][j - padSize][0], coz there’s only 1 channel in this case?

Comment: how do you display it? there may be an error in the rendering code?

Comment: I am using ImageJ

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. As @Stefano Buro suggested, you have to output the image in as a 1D array, instead of as a 3D array which I was doing.